# How to confirm the execution order of .mk when building AOSP

Tags: makefile

After the make command is executed, many mk files will be called and executed.
The issue is:

1. How can we determine the calling order of these mk files?
2. Can these .mk files be compiled and debugged separately?

Build AOSP：

1.source build/envsetup.sh

2.lunch xxx_project

3.make -f build/core/sysprop.mk

4.make

step3 error：
10:12:04 Unknown option: -f

##### failed to build some targets

step4 success

Expectation:

1.We can compile and debug the .mk separately

2.We have a way to determine which .mk files are compiled by the make command and what is their order.

Comment: You seem to be asking about building unmodified software from the AOSP repository.  This is the wrong place for such a question.  Start by reading the relevant build documentation -- both the online docs and any that are bundled with the source.  If you still have questions after that then the AOSP project team and community would be the best place to go for answers.

Comment: I have solved this problem, the solution is as follows 
1.And the log in .mk files 
2.lunch 
3.Determine the order through log printing

$(echo '$(warning my_log )')